# WAMP server yellow even though port is open

Tags: php, apache, wamp

My wamp icon is yellow and when i test the port used by apache I get this response

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 8080 =====

Your port 8080 is actually used by :

Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25

This seems like it is the correct program, so i am confused as to why it is still yellow.  Also the httpd.conf file references port 8080.  Can anyone help?/
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you already have a running instance of Apache

Comment: Thanks.  Turned out it was the mysql port that was taken, funny nobody seems to mention this in the troubleshooting